# Implements vs Binary Compatibility

Tags: vba, vb6

I have one VB6 ActiveX DLL that exposes a class `INewReport`. I added some new methods to this class and I was able to rebuild it and keep binary compatibility.

I have a second DLL that exposes a class `clsNewReport`, which implements the first class using:

```
Implements RSInterfaces.INewReport
```

Since I added new methods to `INewReport`, I had to also add those new methods to `clsNewReport`.

However, when I try to compile the second DLL, I get the binary-compatibility error *"...class implemented an interface in the version-compatible component, but not in the current project"*.

[image]

I'm not sure what is happening here. Since I'm only adding to the class, why can't I maintain binary compatibility with the second DLL? Is there any way around this?

Comment: One of the quirks of binary compatibility in VB6 is that you can add methods (which is the quirk), but have to append them. If you happened to add any methods before any methods that are already in the signature (meaning, didn't put them at the bottom of the code window), you'll break compatibility. Might that be the problem?

Comment: @BobRodes: That doesn't sound quite right. Do you have any links to support that?

Comment: Looks like my memory has played me false, sorry. You can add methods (that's the quirk), but can't remove or change the signature of existing methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a correct explanation of what is happening, and some potential workarounds.

I made up a test case which reproduced the problem in the description and then dumped the IDL using OLEView from the old & new DLL which contained the interface.

Here is a diff of the old (left) and new IDL from INewReport:

[image]

Important differences:

- The UUID of `interface _INewReport` has *changed*
- A typedef called `INewReport___v0` has been added which refers to the *original* UUID of the interface

(I assume that this is also what is happening to the code referred to in the question.)

So now in the client project the bincomp DLL refers to the original interface UUID; but that UUID only matches against a different name (`INewReport___v0` instead of `INewReport`) than it did originally. I think this is the reason VB6 thinks there is a bincomp mismatch.

---

How to fix this problem? I've not been able to do anything in VB6 that would allow you to use the updated interface DLL with the client code without having to break bincomp of the client code.

**A (bad) option** could be to just change the client DLL to use project compatibility... but that may or may not be acceptable in your circumstances. It could cause whatever uses the client DLL to break unless all the consumers were also recompiled. (And this could potentially cause a cascade of broken bincomp).

**A better but more complex option** would be to define the interface in IDL itself, use the MIDL compiler to generate a typelib (TLB file), and reference that directly. Then you would have full control over the interface naming, etc. You could use the IDL generated from OLEView as a starting point for doing this.

This second option assumes that the interface class is really truly an interface only and has no functional code in it.

---

Here's how I setup a case to reproduce this:

Step 1. Original interface definition - class called `INewReport` set to binary compatible:

```
Sub ProcA()    
End Sub    

Sub ProcB()    
End Sub
```

Step 2. Create a test client DLL which implements `INewReport`, also set to binary compatible:

```
Implements INewReport    

Sub INewReport_ProcA()    
End Sub

Sub INewReport_ProcB()    
End Sub
```

Step 3: Add `ProcC` to `INewReport` and recompile (which also registers the newly built DLL):

(above code, plus:)

```
Sub ProcC()    
End Sub
```

Step 4: Try to run or compile the test client DLL - instantly get the OP's error. No need to change any references or anything at all.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. You seem to have duplicated the issue perfectly, and cascading dependencies is indeed the problem I'm running into (there are over 100 DLLs in the project). But I'm not sure I want to manually edit the IDL. (I don't even have OleView.exe available on the old Windows XP system I'm developing on.) I think the bottom line is that, even though I did not break binary compatibility in my server DLL, this will break binary compatibility in any client DLLs that implement this interface.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to recreate your problem, using something similar to DaveInCaz's code. I tried a number of things to fix it, probably repeating things you've already tried. I came up with a possible hypothesis as to why this is happening. It doesn't fix the problem, but it may throw some additional light on it.

Quoting from [This doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa263546%28v%3dvs.60%29#version-compatibility-for-interfaces):

> To ensure compatibility, Visual Basic places certain restrictions on changes you make to default interfaces. Visual Basic allows you to add new classes, and to enhance the default interface of any existing class by adding properties and methods. Removing classes, properties, or methods, or changing the arguments of existing properties or methods, will cause Visual Basic to issue incompatibility warnings.

Another quote:

> The ActiveX rule you must follow to ensure compatibility with multiple interfaces is simple: *once an interface is in use, it can never be changed*. The interface ID of a standard interface is fixed by the type library that defines the interface.

So, here's a hypothesis. The first quote mentions the *default* interface, which suggests that it may not be possible to alter custom interfaces in any way. That's suggested by the second quote as well. You're able to alter the interface class, because you are essentially altering its default interface. However, when you attempt to alter the implementing class in kind, to reflect the changes in your interface, your implementation reference is pointing to the older version of the interface, which no longer exists. Of course, the error message doesn't hint at this at all, because it appears to be based on the idea that you didn't attempt to implement the interface.

I haven't been able to prove this, but looking at DaveInCaz's answer, the fact that the UUID has changed seems to bear this idea out.